# Find the function satisfying the differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the function satisfying the differential equation 
$$ f'(t)-f(t)=-7t\;\;\;\;\; f(3)=5 $$

For some reason I've never completely understood what f'(t) and f(t) or function notation very well. Is f'(t) the same as dt/dx in this situation with f(t) = x? anywho... on to the question.

would this in turn be.

$$ x' - x = -7t $$

$$ dx/dt - x = -7t $$

Solve for a homogenous equation.

$$ dx/dt - x = 0 $$

$$ dx/dt = x $$
$$ dx/xdt = 1 $$
$$ dx/x = dt $$

Integrate

$$ ln|x| = t+c $$
$$ x = c*e^t $$ 
this is where I am stuck.

Comment: Hint: $e^{-t}$ is an integrating factor for the original equation.

Answer (score 2):

The general solution of your equation is $f(t)=f_0(t)+f_{u}(t)$, where $f_0$ is a partial solution, and $f_u$ is the general solution of the corresponding homogeneous equation $f'(t)-f(t)=0$. This one can be solved by separating and integrating, which yields us $f_u(t)=Ce^t$, $C \in \mathbb{R}$. To find a partial solution, it's enough to look for all linear functions satisfying it. One of these is $f_0(t)=7t+7$.

Therefore, the set of solutions is given by $f(t)=Ce^t+7t+7$. Taking into consideration the second equaltion, we obtain $C=-\frac{23}{e^3}$ and ultimately $f(t)=-23e^{t-3}+7t+7$.

Comment: Thank you, I'm taking the class online and the instructor is damned near impossible to follow. Any suggestions on a good resource for this stuff?

Comment: @DavidScidmore Already https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Examples_of_differential_equations would help your understanding, it seems.

Answer (score 0):

$f'(t)-f(t)=-7t$, $f"(t)-f'(t)=-7$, $f^{(3)}(t)-f"(t)=0$, $f"(t)=Ae^t$, $f'(t)=Ae^t+B$, $f(t)=Ae^t+Bt+C$, thus

$f'(t)-f(t)=-Bt-C+B=-7t$, $B=7, C=7$. $f(t)=Ae^t+7t+7$, $f(3)=5$, find $A$.

Comment: The method is rather specific (actually it can only be applied when the RHS is a polynomial and even then, it becomes impractical as soon as the degree of this polynomial is not very small).